# Stuck on this cyclic 3-variables-inequality with constraint

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, tangent-line-method

Problem Statement:

For $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=3$, I'd want to prove that
$$\frac{1}{a^2+b+c}+\frac{1}{b^2+a+c} +\frac {1}{c^2+a+b} \leq1 .$$

I am a beginner when it comes to inequalities. This problem appeared on my test and I tried everything I knew:

1. AM-GM-HM,
2. Cauchy-Schwarz,
3. homogenization,
4. elimination,
5. properties of quadratic functions,
6. etc ....

but I was not not able to prove it. In many cases I got the upper bound as greater than one, so I knew that my result was very weak compared to the inequality given.

I just need a hint. :-)

Answer (score 3):

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^2+b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1+b+c}{(1+b+c)(a^2+b+c)}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{1+b+c}{(a+b+c)^2}=1.$$

Comment: This solution is rather elegant in my eyes as the initial constraint and 
Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz are perfectly combined (+1) to yield the result.
*But Michael, why don't you take the few seconds to write out
'Cauchy-Schwarz', instead of the acronym?* With which many readers are **not familiar**.
Would be a real gain, now and in the future since the reader can concentrate on the content without having first to decipher the accompanying text. Even if the OP writes "I just need a hint.".

Comment: @Hanno Because it's very known as AM-GM for example. I am always ready to explain, if somebody looks for this. Thank you!

Comment: Michael, I do not share your opinion regarding your first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Also, the Tangent Line method helps.

Indeed, $$1-\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^2+b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{a^2-a+3}\right)=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2-a}{a^2-a+3}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2-a}{a^2-a+3}-\frac{a-1}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-1)^2(3-a)}{a^2-a+3}\geq0.$$